# Multiple Buttons for Linking Contact to Flow (Case Object)

Tags: case, flow

Ok, here is my problem and maybe someone can come up with a solution. I'm working with a nonprofit which has a volunteer hotline. They have for years been using a static flat file database to capture intake info for their volunteer hotline. The script has zero logic, its just question/answer with no logical branching. I created a really nice script in Flow with some pretty niffty decision trees and programming. They way I initially set it up was that the volunteer hotline rep would go to the Contact tab, see if a contact already existed and if so scroll down to the Cases related list and click the New Case button which through a Visual Force page script I over wrote the button programming with would then take the user to the Flow script. If the Contact did not exist, they create one, and then follow the same procedure. It all worked just fine. Click the button, goes to the Flow script, go through the questions, create record and bingo the Case fields are all populated and the Case is attached to the correct contact.

So this worked just fine, but as usual we had some up happy camper volunteers who didn't want to use the script. So I added another button with the original New Case scripting to the Contact layout. But, every time that got clicked it still went to the Flow script instead of the Case object where the volunteers who didn't want to use the script could manually fill in the fields without going through the scripted questions. As this was the Case I simply created a tab so they could created a Contact or pull one up, go to the Volunteer Hotline Case tab, go through the Flow script and then manually attached it to the Contact.

Here is the problem, now they are not happy with this solution. They want to have it both ways i.e. 2 buttons, one which goes from Contact to New Case (with Flow script) and one that goes from the Contact to the Case tab so the fields can be filled in manually. And it thats not enough, when a rep is using the Flow when they reach the end and a new Case record is created they also want the Case to automatically close, which I don't this is possible. Does anyone have a solution where I can have 2 buttons on the Contact layout which will fulfill their needs, i.e. one that goes to the Flow script from the Contact, so that it creates a new case with attached contact, and one that goes from the Contact to the Case so the Case fields can be filled out manually. Personally if they are to lazy to simply hit the close case button, to bad.

Answer (score 0):

Glenn, what I'm hearing you say is that you're frustrated with the non-profit volunteers for not wanting to work exclusively with your flow script and when using it, they want the case to automatically be created and closed without having to save it themselves. It sounds as though you're feeling as though you're in a no-win situation where no matter what you do, you can't please everyone. I'm also hearing in your post that you're having a difficult time managing what you feel are unrealistic expectations.

I've found it very important when working with any organization to establish a clear limit on the scope of any project I'm engaged in. It's essential to have the full support and buy-in from management, including sign-off on a design/process before the project begins. Without those things, any project is doomed to failure with respect to acceptance and implementation by users.

When we change a user's UI, it's important to talk with users first to ask them what would be helpful to them. What do they like about the existing UI? What would they like to see changed? Having their input can be invaluable and also helps give them a sense of ownership in the project; even if they don't receive what they ask for. Users will feel like they were at least given the opportunity to voice their preferences rather than being totally ignored. Starting in this manner helps make them a "stakeholder" in the success of a project. I'm not suggesting you didn't include them as I don't know if you did.

If this is a volunteer gig for you, I recommend you speak with the organization's management to set some clear boundaries, establish project scope and limits on what you can do, are willing to do, along with the kind of support and buy-in/sign-off you want from them before you'll be willing to do any additional work.

As I'm confident you know, consistency is important. You may want to ask if the non-flow volunteers are more/less consistent compared to the volunteers who use the flows in collecting the data. Is one group faster or slower than the other? Assuming you want to continue, find a measurable means to determine what work process is helpful and what isn't. If you don't want to continue, simply tell the organization and go find another group that will appreciate what you can offer them. Volunteering your technical skills should be an enjoyable experience for all, not a struggle or battle of wits. I hope this is helpful as I don't think telling you how to create additional buttons is the kind of answer you really want or need in response to your question.